# Changing background color on any number input higher than 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My question is simple so I hope it shouldn't be so hard to solve. Not as hard as it is for me at least :).

```
<div id="block">
    <input type="number" min="0" value="0">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wbrnmldr/9n60r82y/2/

[EDIT ]Ok since I'm clearly too dumb to explain it properly I will do it again. The grey  around the input field is supposed to go yellow, not the input field itself.

So I have this simple div as seen above. What is supposed to happen is that the background color of this div changes from #F1F1F1 to #FFD200 anytime the input value doesn't equal 0 anymore. And to make it more complicated, if the value is zero again it should return to #F1F1F1. I already got it to work when submitting the value but my goal is to see it happen in real-time.

Can anybody help me tackle this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Following are some of the things I tried but I didn't get to work:

```
$('.input').each(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this);

    inputValue.data('oldValue', inputValue.val());

    inputValue.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste",   function(event){
        if (inputValue.data('oldValue') != inputValue.val()) {
        inputValue.data('oldValue', inputValue.val());

        document.getElementsByClassName('block').style.backgroundColor = "#FFD200";
    }
    
    });
});
```

```
function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("tracker-option-block").style.backgroundColor = "FFD200";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in order to solve this

Comment: Just a bit of JavaScript using the onChange event…

Comment: fiddle blocked for some people. put your code here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add a block of code as a comment.

Comment: Ah yes, I never asked a question, just figuring out the buttons lol

Comment: The button to add a Stack Snippet looks like `<>` in a page...

Comment: But honestly, there are plenty of questions about how to react to changes in value in an input...

Comment: From the now-deleted code comment (edit: now added to question) your issue is that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so does not have a `.style.` property.  Which is one reason why we use jquery - no need to iterate collections manually (*uck*)

Comment: Most likely answers your question: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693852/2181514)

Comment: [`bind` was deprecated in jQuery 3.0](https://api.jquery.com/bind/), after the introduction of [`on` in jQuery 1.7](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen any input value changes using ['input' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) like this:

```js
document
.querySelector('#block input')
.addEventListener('input', event => {
  document.querySelector('#block').style.backgroundColor = 
    event.target.value === '0' ? '#F1F1F1' : '#FFD200';
})
```

```css
#block {
    margin: 10px;
    padding:30px;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    /* target color: #FFD200;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <input type="number" min="0" value="0">
</div>
```

Refs: [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the grey <div> should go yellow, not the input field itself.

Comment: @Wybren fixed, sorry didn't notice before

Comment: Yooo thanks man! I am forever grateful.

Comment: You should bind on `input`, not `change` so the effect is immediate.

Comment: @freedomn-m correct, ty for notice, I changed snippet

Answer (score -1):

you can use addEventListener (change) to get value always on change input
then change background color

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("change",function(){
if(document.querySelector('#block input').value>0){
document.querySelector('#block input').style.backgroundColor= "#54BAB9";
}
else{
document.querySelector('#block input').style.backgroundColor= "#F1F1F1";
}
})
```

Answer (score -4):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMnZO.png)

please remember that text in an input doesn't have its background color , rather it have color that i've shown in the code that you can use,
Happy programming!

Comment: This does not answer the question, apart from being just an image

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough but what I meant was the grey <div> needs to change to yellow when the input isn't zero anymore.

Comment: inputs have a background color but the actual texts in an input doesn't have a a background color! Sry my bad!